# Android: instantiate a class extending ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

How can I instantiate objects of type `ArrayAdapter` in Android

```
private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LeScanRecord>
```

LeScanRecord is a class too.

Comment: check some custom listview examples. All you need to do is define right constructor and just create new object with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
   public class LeDeviceListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LeScanRecord> {

    Context context;

    public LeDeviceListAdapter(Context context, int itemResource, List<LeScanRecord> itemList ) {
        super(context, itemResource, itemList);
        this.context = context;
        this.itemResource = itemResource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (null == convertView) {
            convertView = newView(parent);
            // your functionality here
         }   
        return 
    }

 private View newView(ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(itemResource, parent, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Please me it an answer. If you find it helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can create objects of ArrayAdapter and use it as the ListView adapter :

```
ArrayAdapter<LeScanRecord> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<LeScanRecord>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

in which, `values` is a list of `LeScanRecord` objects to display in the listview.

For more information on using ArrayAdapter, you can study [Simple ListView tutorial by AndroidExample.com.](http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90)

You can also create custom Adapter for list components (ListView, GridView,Spinner , ....) by extending `BaseAdapter`, which is easier and more straightforward.

I recommend you to study another great article by [Ravi Tamada, on Android ListViews, published on AndroidHive.info.](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/)